# doubt on patent WO 2010052608 A1

Tags: wo2010052608a1

All description in this claim is very ordinary and common, why is it be authorized?
For example, claim1, almost every monitoring device (includes parameter of EtCO2) has the function of it. Why this function can be authorized?

Answer (score 1):

The European Patent Office, which acted as International Search Authority for this PCT application, seems to agree with you, as they found all claims to be unallowable over multiple prior art documents:

http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/WO2010052608

Answer (score 0):

WO 2010052608 A1 is an application, not a grant. You can apply for a patent on anything you want -- that doesn't mean it will be granted.

If you think there's prior art for this you may be able to register your observations.

Comment: Opposition is only possible after grant. However, the EP examination procedure for this PCT application has only just started. You may be able to submit a third-party observation, but what is the point given that the office itself has already cited multiple X documents?

Comment: Also, jurisdiction for filing an opposition against a granted patent does NOT depend on the location of the opponent, but on the jurisdication where the patent was granted. I.e., opposition against a granted European Patent is always before the EPO, no matter where the opponent is coming from.